# Authentication in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My authentication requires the verification of the role of the user (either administrator or client user). If you are the web administrator, you should not stop accessing the client users. How would you do in that case? regards.

I'm not talking about the rules of firebase, I want to verify the user before authenticating. Since I have an app for clients, messengers and a web admin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: I would like to add that the question here is quite vague and unclear.

Comment: That can only be done if you allow read rules to be true for unauthenticated users on a specific node. That node would need to have keys of some identifying string (email? user name?) and then their role. The app would have to query that node for the identifying string to then capture what role they are and then proceed to authentication. The bottom line? *Don't do it*. Find some other solution.